# Change axis of matrix - Python (concatenate)

Tags: numpy, matrix, axis

I would like concatenate two matricies with different size

```
[[1 1 1]
 [2 3 2]
 [5 5 3]
 [3 2 5]
 [4 4 4]]

[[1 3 2 5 4]
 [1 2 5 3 4]]
```

to have this matrix

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 3 2 3 2]
 [5 5 3 2 5]
 [3 2 5 5 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]
```

I know size of matricies are differents ((5, 3), 'VS', (2, 5))
but i want concatenate these matricies between them.
It's possible to change axis of second matrix ?
Thanks !

Comment: Just `np.concatenate([matrix1, matrix2.T], axis=1)`, or even shorter `np.r_[matrix1, matrix2.T]`.

Comment: Yes use `transpose`